# Time complexity calculation for my algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm

Given a string, find the first non-repeating character in it and return its index. If it doesn't exist, return -1. You may assume the string contain only lowercase letters.

I'm going to define a hash that tracks the occurrence of characters. Traverse the string from left to right, check if the current character is in the hash, continue if yes, otherwise in another loop traverse  the rest of the string to see if the current character exists. Return the index if not and update the hash if it exists.

```
def firstUniqChar(s):

    track = {}
    for index, i in enumerate(s):
        if i in track:
            continue
        elif i in s[index+1:]: # For the last element, i in [] holds False
            track[i] = 1
            continue
        else:
            return index
    return -1

firstUniqChar('timecomplexity')
```

What's the time complexity (average and worst) of my algorithm?

Comment: _find the first non-repeating character_ - should this mean e.g. for `abbacdec` the algorithm would return `a` (it doesn't _repeat_) or `d` (it _exists once_ only)?

Comment: Non-repeating means exists once only@miraculixx In your case, return 5

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your algorithm has time complexity of `O(kn)` where `k` is the number of unique characters in the string. If `k` is a constant then it is `O(n)`. As the problem description clearly bounds the number of alternatives for elements ("assume lower-case (ASCII) letters"), thus `k` is constant and your algorithm runs in `O(n)` time on this problem. Even though n will grow to infinite, you will only make `O(1)` slices of the string and your algorithm will remain `O(n)`. If you removed `track`, then it would be `O(n²)`:

```
In [36]: s = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' * 10000

In [37]: %timeit firstUniqChar(s)
100 loops, best of 3: 18.2 ms per loop

In [38]: s = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' * 20000

In [37]: %timeit firstUniqChar(s)
10 loops, best of 3: 36.3 ms per loop

In [38]: s = 'timecomplexity' * 40000 + 'a'

In [39]: %timeit firstUniqChar(s)
10 loops, best of 3: 73.3 ms per loop
```

It pretty much holds there that the `T(n)` is still of `O(n)` complexity - it scales exactly linearly with number of characters in the string, even though this is the worst-case scenario for your algorithm - there is no single character that is be unique.

---

I will present a not-that efficient, but simple and smart method here; count the character histogram first with `collections.Counter`; then iterate over the characters finding the one

```
from collections import Counter
def first_uniq_char_ultra_smart(s):
    counts = Counter(s)
    for i, c in enumerate(s):
        if counts[c] == 1:
            return i

    return -1

first_uniq_char('timecomplexity')
```

This has time complexity of `O(n)`; `Counter` counts the histogram in `O(n)` time and we need to enumerate the string again for `O(n)` characters. However in practice I believe my algorithm has low constants, because it uses a standard dictionary for `Counter`.

And lets make a very stupid brute-force algorithm. Since you can assume that the string contains only lower-case letters, then use that assumption:

```
import string
def first_uniq_char_very_stupid(s):
    indexes = []
    for c in string.ascii_lowercase:
        if s.count(c) == 1:
            indexes.append(s.find(c))

    # default=-1 is Python 3 only
    return min(indexes, default=-1)
```

Let's test my algorithm and some algorithms found in the other answers, on Python 3.5. I've chosen a case that is pathologically bad for *my* algorithm:

```
In [30]: s = 'timecomplexity' * 10000 + 'a'

In [31]: %timeit first_uniq_char_ultra_smart(s)
10 loops, best of 3: 35 ms per loop

In [32]: %timeit karin(s)
100 loops, best of 3: 11.7 ms per loop

In [33]: %timeit john(s)
100 loops, best of 3: 9.92 ms per loop

In [34]: %timeit nicholas(s)
100 loops, best of 3: 10.4 ms per loop

In [35]: %timeit first_uniq_char_very_stupid(s)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.55 ms per loop
```

So, my stupid algorithm is the fastest, because it finds the `a` at the end and bails out. And my smart algorithm is slowest, One more reason for bad performance of my algorithm besides this being worst case is that `OrderedDict` is written in C on Python 3.5, and `Counter` is in Python.

---

Let's make a better test here:

```
In [60]: s = string.ascii_lowercase * 10000

In [61]: %timeit nicholas(s)
100 loops, best of 3: 18.3 ms per loop

In [62]: %timeit karin(s)
100 loops, best of 3: 19.6 ms per loop

In [63]: %timeit john(s)
100 loops, best of 3: 18.2 ms per loop

In [64]: %timeit first_uniq_char_very_stupid(s)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.89 ms per loop
```

So it appears that the "stupid" algorithm of mine isn't all that stupid at all, it exploits the speed of C while minimizing the number of iterations of Python code being run, and wins clearly in this problem.

Comment: Ooh, nice.  I like this one best so far.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Actually this was slower than Karin's, funny, I thought OrderedDict would be slower.

Comment: Interesting, I am now still surprised my algorithm is faster than yours in your case and some other *s* I assigned (given that Counter is written in Python as you said). I suggest you also time my code in Jupyter. Actually, I was pretty sure that the worst case of my algorithm is O(n^2) but what I was more interested is the average time complexity (seems nobody's answered explicitly) since I found the problem here is very case-sensitive, i.e., it seems to depend much on s.

Comment: Mine could really be faster by a factor of 3-4 if only the Counter was not implemented as it is implemented now.

Comment: @NicholasLiu edited my answer, your algorithm runs in O(n) time.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, really appreciate your time! But I think k is the number of **repeated** characters plus **1**. I am thinking like when n is large, it's expected that we've met every repeated letter before the 1st unique letter. For each time we touch a new repeated letter, O(n) is needed. And one more O(n) is needed for the 1st unique letter, then quit.

Answer (score 5):

<s>As others have noted, your algorithm is `O(n²)` due to nested linear search.</s> As discovered by @Antti, the OP's algorithm is linear and bound by `O(kn)` for `k` as the number of all possible lowercase letters.

My proposition for an `O(n)` solution:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

def first_unique_char(string):
    duplicated = OrderedDict()  # ordered dict of char to boolean indicating duplicate existence
    for s in string:
        duplicated[s] = s in duplicated

    for char, is_duplicate in duplicated.items():
        if not is_duplicate:
            return string.find(char)
    return -1

print(first_unique_char('timecomplexity'))  # 4
```

Comment: Yours returns the index, not the character though :)

Comment: Woah you're right - I read too far into the function name -_- Eww this will make it not as nice :(

Comment: Actually, your algorithm is so fast that you could just return `string.find(char)`

Comment: Haha thanks for the save! I just really wanted to keep the `duplicated[s] = s in duplicated` and was almost heartbroken!

Comment: Do you need `string.find`? Why not enumerate the values of `duplicated` and return the index of the first False value?

Comment: @friendlydog `duplicated` is an ordered dictionary, so it will not contain all of the letters that the original string had if there were duplicates. That means the index may not match up with the original string.

Comment: Ah, I see. My mistake.

Comment: It turns out John's might be a bit faster despite using 2 hashing containers, see my answer for some timings.

Comment: Actually op's original algorithm is O(n).

Comment: I guess it depends if you want to consider the set of unique characters finite in this case :) I agree it will be better than `O(n²)` in the average case because of the conditional linear search, but I still think of it as such in the worst case for a string with all unique letters. I see the argument for capping the set of unique letters to a constant, but that constant seems like it would be much larger than `n` in most cases.

Comment: Well, the problem description did say that the characters are "lowercase letters", which clearly limits their number. Assuming that it also meant "ASCII lowercase letters", because otherwise such a restriction would otherwise be meaningless, the constant here is 26, which is not even theoretical any longer. Thus no matter what the `n` is, there are ever only maximum of 26 slices taken.

Comment: I agree and have placed an edit on my answer. Nice research :)

Answer (score 4):

Your algorithm is O(n<sup>2</sup>), because you have a "hidden" iteration over a slice of `s` inside the loop over `s`.

A faster algorithm would be:

```
def first_unique_character(s):
    good = {} # char:idx
    bad = set() # char
    for index, ch in enumerate(s):
        if ch in bad:
            continue
        if ch in good: # new repeat
            bad.add(ch)
            del good[ch]
        else:
            good[ch] = index

    if not good:
        return -1

    return min(good.values())
```

This is O(n) because the `in` lookups use hash tables, and the number of distinct characters should be much less than `len(s)`.

Comment: better but not quite `O(n)` yet because `sorted` is `O(n log n)` as per [Python TimeComplexity](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity)

Comment: Replace `sorted(good.values())[0]` with `min(good.values())` (use `good.viewvalues()` on Python 2.x to avoid temporary `list`s) and it's back to `O(n)`. Mind you, the `sorted` step was `O(n log n)` in terms of number of non-repeated values, which is presumably much smaller than the total string size (which is the `n` in the other big-Os), so it's probably not huge, but then, `min` does what you want directly with work that's guaranteed to be irrelevant to the big-O cost (since the main algorithm is `O(n)` on string length, and the `min` step is `O(n)` on a smaller `n`).

Comment: It might still end up being `O(n^2)` though because of the `in bad` and `in good` searches

Comment: @miraculixx: Python's `set` and `dict` are implemented as hash tables; yes, the worst case lookup cost for a hash table is `O(n)`, but actual hash collisions are impossible for single characters in Python (the full Unicode space is <21 bits in size right now, and I believe Python's hash codes are at least 32 bits on all builds, and 64 bits on 64 bit builds), so the collisions would only be bucket collisions with mismatched hashes, and as the `dict` grew, rehashing would tend to make collisions at one size disappear at larger sizes. In practice, the lookups would be `O(1)`.

Comment: So really, you're right that `O(n^2)` is technically the worst case scenario, but it would be hard as hell if not impossible to trigger it, and it's usually not worth worrying about that possibility in Python, particularly modern Python 3 (where strings above a certain length use a cryptographically secure hashing algorithm with a per-interpreter-launch key, which means keys that collide in one session won't collide in another session, and renders DoS via intentionally triggering hash collisions a likely non-issue). Just treat `dict` and `set` as "`O(1)`, but with a higher constant factor".

Comment: @miraculixx: Sorting is O(n log n) but n there is a different n!  I tried to address that concern with my last note about the number of distinct characters being much less than the total length, but anyway @ShadowRanger was right--I should have used `min()`.  So now I do.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: Thanks for your comments.  I agree with all of them.

Comment: It turns out that yours is now fastest.

Comment: Indeed, the sorting has `O(1)` time complexity here! But so does `min` and in this case (well, always really) `min` is faster.

Comment: Actually op's original algorithm is O(n).

Comment: @ShadowRanger yes but Big O is a worst case view, and in the worst case all characters end up  in `good` so you get `O(n log n)` for the sort. Also as per [Python Timecomplexities](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) set and dict lookups have worst case O(n), not O(1), though I guess it really depends on the actual implementation. Average and best case I agree.